# Loading image with glide is slow

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have app connect with server and when pics load seems so slow and when scroll that up and down seems glide want read image again! 
This is my adapter of glide:

**DataAdapter**:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android;


    public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android) {
        this.context = context;
        this.android = android;
    }


    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(android.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.tv_version.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
        viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(android.get(i).getApi());

        // load image into imageview using glide
        Glide.with(context).load("http://memaraneha.ir/Erfan/images/"+android.get(i).getPic())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.truiton)
                .error(R.drawable.truiton)
                .into(viewHolder.tv_image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv_name,tv_version,tv_api_level;
        public ImageView tv_image;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
            tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);
            tv_image= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

        }
    }

}
```

If any one can help please do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this when you get image from `URL`, this code reduces the size of that image

you can also do this,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //save scaled down image to cache dir
    newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File imageFile = new File(filePath);

    // write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
```

check [this example](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/grid-recyclerview-with-images-and-text.html)

Answer (score 5):

I used `dontTransform()` method and it almost saved me a second. Images are loaded to the list really first.

Answer (score 0):

use **diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)**.

for more visit this [Click Here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)

Comment: How is that going to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below parts for your `glide`:

```
.thumbnail( 0.5f )
.diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
```

Like this:

```
Glide.with( context )
            .load( arrayList.get().getImage_url())
            .thumbnail( 0.5f )
            .override( 200, 200 )
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
            .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
            .into( imageView );
```