# Glide takes time to Load Large image Android

Tags: android, android-glide

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
        requestOptions.dontTransform();
        requestOptions.fitCenter();
        requestOptions.priority(Priority.HIGH);

        Glide.with(context)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                .load(images.get(position))
                .into(holder.pictureView);
```

Image height width (JPEG Image, 4608 × 3456 pixels)

Size : 6,149.64 KB (6,297,232 bytes)

Large Image takes time to Load first time using Glide 4.7.1
Please Provide me solution for it. I have tried using fresco too its taking more time than Glide.

Comment: Isn't it natural that doing something takes time? For example processing large image is expected to take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this when you get the image from `URL,` this code reduces the size of that image.

Here you can find your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674227/loading-image-with-glide-is-slow)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //save scaled down image to cache dir
    newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File imageFile = new File(filePath);

    // write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
```

**OR**

you can use alternative Glide options.

```
Glide.with(context)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                .load(images.get(position))
                .error(R.drawable.no_internet_con)
                .thumbnail(.1f)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
                .into(holder.pictureView);
```

Comment: Linking to an earlier made solution without providing additional information is considered trivial and should be a comment instead.

Comment: @ZUNJAE I was considering it was a comment but unfortunately going wrong.

Comment: Please Provide Brief Information what are you trying to say?

Comment: @MihirModi reduce the size of the image then load in glide

Comment: sorry but my client has said no to resize the quality of image. in Web when i load that image with same network its load max within 10 sec while in app glide takes much more time than web.

Comment: @MihirModiI think the quality of Image should not be reduced after reducing size.

Comment: you can use this property `.thumbnail(.1f)` its shows blurry effect on imagview after download 0.1 of image or you can show place holder property like  `.placeholder(R.drawable.image)`

Answer (score -2):

**It's depends on two things.**

```
01. Your Internet Speed. 
02. Yor photo size.
```