# Slow loading of Images using Glide on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-gridlayout

I have a recyclerView with a grid layout, at a time 6 cards are being displayed on the screen and JSON with 10 objects are called and for image loading, I'm using glide

Now Image loading was not up to the marking
So I search more regarding Glide and found a method for calling the thumbnail

```
Glide
     .with(Context)
     .load(url)
     .thumbnail(0.25f)
     .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
     .into(ImageView);
```

But still wasn't helpful much

then **I use another method of calling a RequestBuilder**
It did help but not the desired level

Can anyone suggest what else I could do to decrease the loading time of images to make the user experience better?

Comment: use image compression code for compress image after use that image it maybe helpfull to load an image in less time.

Comment: I hope it'll help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39674379

Answer (score 1):

Use these options (In kotlin) -

```
GlideApp.with(mContext)
                .apply(getRectangleRequestOptions(true))
                .load(url)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .into(layout.bannerAdapterImg)
```

Where `getSquareRequestOptions` is -

```
fun getSquareRequestOptions(isCenterCrop:Boolean=true): RequestOptions {
        return RequestOptions().also {
            it.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
            it.error(R.drawable.ic_err_image)
            it.override(200, 200)                         // override size as you need
            it.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)   //If your images are always same
            it.format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)        // the decode format - this will not use alpha at all

            if(isCenterCrop)
                it.centerCrop()
            else
                it.fitCenter()
        }
    }
```

*For java code just update `getSquareRequestOptions` function in java.

This is the best glide can do. If it still takes time than compress images from server side.